# Errors while configuring JPA with Hibernate in standalone application

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to run Hibernate with JPA in standalone application. I see it's a bit difficult task. I was trying many things but mostly I failed.

I got this Exception when i add logging libraries:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: slf4j-impl jar is mutually exclusive with log4j-to-slf4j jar (the first routes calls from SLF4J to Log4j, the second from Log4j to SLF4J)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContextFactory.<init>(SLF4JLoggerContextFactory.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:85)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:39)
at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.<init>(Log4jLogger.java:35)
at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider.getLogger(Log4jLoggerProvider.java:33)
at org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.find(LoggerProviders.java:37)
at org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.<clinit>(LoggerProviders.java:32)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:2163)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2259)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:144)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flume.Event
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 60 more
```

My pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
<name>ccc</name>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <junit-version>3.8.1</junit-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JSR 303 Form Validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <mainClass>pl.semantyk.WNMain.WNPMain</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When i remove logging libraries i got :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.

at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:147)
at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:171)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:326)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:58)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at pl.semantyk.Database.EntityManagerProvider.getEm(EntityManagerProvider.java:17)
at pl.semantyk.dao.AbstractDao.<init>(AbstractDao.java:16)
```

I put persistence.xml file int src/META-INF/ directory. Contenet of this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="persist_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>pl.semantyk.dao.JednostkaDaoImpl</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/semantyk"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I ran out of ideas. Any suggestions will be very helpful.
PS. Sorry for my English.

Comment: So is it working now? If yes, then write how you solved it

Comment: well someone give me an answer but deleted it. Problem was with some old log4j libs in project build path.

Comment: now i have IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity even if i add this class to persistence.xml in class tag.

Comment: Make sure you annotate your class JednostkaDaoImpl properly with @Entity, @Table(name="db_table_name") and other annotations

Comment: It worked in tests but in main application i still get - PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persist_unit. I run under IntelliJ if it means.

Comment: Ok I fixed this. After building persistence.xml was under folder target/classes instead of target/classes/META-INF/. I created META-INF in classes director and copied persistence.xml into.